# Mysql - Not able to change or add a new password

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, server, passwords, root

In Ubuntu 20.04, I am getting an error `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` while accessing `mysql`.

I have completely removed and installed mysql server and client.

while running `sudo mysql_secure_installation` command, it ask me to enter `Enter password for user root:` if I enter with or without password it will show an above error.

Before uninstall it, I tried to update the password in mysql shell but it didn't support.

Please help to get my `'root'@'localhost'` password or how can I update it.

Comment: [How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html). Use "Resetting the Root Password: Generic Instructions".

Answer (score 1):

Does root have a password? Check with:

> sudo passwd -S root

if there is an L it is not. Add a password with:

> sudo passwd root

See: https://devanswers.co/install-secure-mysql-server-ubuntu-20-04/